# Origin of some of AOP's terminology

Tags: aop, aspectj, terminology

I would think this question have been asked before, but I was not immediately able to find related SO questions, or articles elsewhere for that matter.

It strikes me that certain terms in AOP are rather strange. It seems I'm not the only one - this [article](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), for instance, notes that "unfortunately, AOP terminology is not particularly intuitive". However, I have not found a resource explaining why they are not more "intuitive", if that's possible.

More specifically: I can somewhat understand "aspect" and "join points" - they seem descriptive enough. But "pointcuts" and "advice" seem somewhat odd. How did these terms come about?

I think knowing the etymology of these terms will help in remembering them better, if not allowing for some insight into the thinking of AOP's designers. At least, I hope this will help me from ever blubbering out nonsensical things like "cut points" or "advice points" in meetings...

Answer (score 1):

Etymology will not help much. You will just have to learn the terminology. But as for historical information about how some terms came about to be used, maybe you need to perform a web search, it is not really a question for Stack Overflow. At least I found some background info about the term [advice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(programming)) for you.

---

**Update:** Actually there are not so many technical terms you need to be familiar with. The following is from one of my AOP slides. I use them in order to introduce AOP to developers when coaching them:

#### What is an aspect?

- An **aspect** contains all necessary elements to implement a cross-cutting concern in a modular way. So, it is much like what a class is for a core concern.
- An aspect can, like a class, contain some kind of "methods" called **advice** and data. It can be a singleton or instantiated multiple times, depending on its usage.
- Because an aspect is defined independently of the core system, we need something else to weave its orthogonal functionality into the core code. This something is called a **pointcut** and determines where an advice should be applied, e.g. before or after certain method calls, upon an exception, when an object is created and so forth.
- Any place or event in the core code where aspect code can potentially be woven in is called a **joinpoint**.

If you need a crib or memory hook, maybe this helps (please note the words in italics):

- The aspect method which *advises* the core code about how to apply a cross-cutting concern, is called **advice**.
- Each *point* in your core code which you can hook into in order to apply a cross-cutting concern, is called a **joinpoint**.
- You *cut* a slice (or subset) off of your core code joinpoints by means of a query syntax (like SQL selects table rows) called **pointcut**.

Comment: I have just updated the original answer by two definitions of technical terms as well as cribs or memory hooks which might help to memorise them.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with your frustration. Each terminology has it's use but everytime I have to deal with AOP I sometimes have to refresh my memory on what each terminology does.

What helps me is that the whole AOP is based on single concept of Method interceptor that can be applied to method, can decide if it needs to take action on that method call and apply custom logic to before and after that method call.

Take a look at Springs org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor and it's inheritance hierarchy. For example the advice is actually an abstract definition of MethodInterceptor and pointcut is the logic of selecting to which methods to apply that advice (or MethodIntercptor).

As far as I can remember even pointcut is just another method interceptor that delegates to a method interceptor.

Comment: I cannot see how this could be helpful in order to memorise the terms. And by the way, AOP is much more than just method interceptors. There are concepts such as inter-type definition (ITD), member read/write interception, error handler and constructor interception and others.

Comment: 1) You can look at constructors as just another method.
<br/>
2) Error handling is done using MethodIntercetors.
<br/>
3) ITD is usually used along with MethodIntercetors.
<br/>
As I ssaid, looking at it in this terms helps me and hopefully others as well.

Comment: ITD changes class structure. And I am not talking about proxy-based "AOP lite" frameworks such as Spring AOP here, I am talking about AspectJ. BTW, if constructors are just another method, why can they not be intercepted by Spring AOP, but only by AspectJ? ;-) Furthermore, the `handler()` pointcut of AspectJ does not use a method interceptor because `try-catch` in Java is not a method call.