# How to prevent my Spring logging aspect from firing?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

My Spring Boot code has a logging aspect that records the time it takes for a method to complete. There are some classes that I don't want this behavior for, so I created a `NoLogging` annotation to place on the class I don't want to run the aspect for. But it's not working at all. I'm still seeing the aspect run on the classes with my annotation. I don't understand Spring AOP enough to know exactly where I define the `!@annotation(org.apa.idem.sso.aspect.logging.NoLogging)`. Can someone help?

Here is the implementation of the aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class IdemSsoLoggingAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * 
     * This method will calculate the Time taken by the public methods
     * 
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     * @return
     * @throws Throwable
     */

    private final static String executionString = "!@annotation(org.apa.idem.sso.aspect.logging.NoLogging) && execution(public * org.apa.idem.sso.rest.*.*(..)) || execution(public * org.apa.idem.sso.web.controller.*.*(..)) || execution(public * org.apa.idem.sso.service.*.*(..)) ||   @annotation(org.apa.idem.erights.Transactional)";

    @Around(executionString)
    public Object logTimeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();
            Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
            stopWatch.stop();
            StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();
            logMessage.append(" execution time: ");
            logMessage.append(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
            logMessage.append(" ms");
            logMessage.append(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
            logMessage.append(".");
            logMessage.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            logMessage.append("(");
            // append args
            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                logMessage.append(args[i]).append(",");
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                logMessage.deleteCharAt(logMessage.length() - 1);
            }
            logMessage.append(")");
            logger.error("****************** Time taken  " + logMessage.toString());
            return retVal;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the second part of the condition in parenthesis because you have OR operators that will be true.

So the first part is the "not annotation" and the second part is everything else but in parenthesis.

```
!@annotation(org.apa.idem.sso.aspect.logging.NoLogging) 
    && (execution(public * org.apa.idem.sso.rest.*.*(..)) 
       || execution(public * org.apa.idem.sso.web.controller.*.*(..)) 
       || execution(public * org.apa.idem.sso.service.*.*(..)) 
       || @annotation(org.apa.idem.erights.Transactional))
```

And also in the pointcut:

```
 @Pointcut("(within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)" +
    " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)" +
    " || within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *))"
    + " && !@annotation(org.apa.idem.sso.aspect.logging.NoLogging)")
```

Comment: I had a feeling my logic there wasn't correct, thanks! But what about the other places where I included !@annotation. Were they necessary?

Comment: Question: what do you mean by "Here is the implementation (I think?) of the aspect:"

Comment: Because I don't know what to call that method. I don't know much about AOP at all.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a small test application to get familiar with Spring AOP and read the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api

Comment: I will never understand why so many so-called programmers think that it is a smart idea to use a tool or technology they know nothing about without learning about it first. "Manuals? Fine, but not for me." This is just unprofessional, sorry. But here the problem is even more basic: How can a programmer have zero knowledge about logical operator precedence? Isn't this what you learn in week 1 whenever learning basic programming in any language or even before that when learning about logical operators? Sorry for the rant and I don't want to personally insult anyone here, but I just don't get it.

Comment: @user1660256, in order to also contribute something useful here, I recommend you to get familiar with AOP terminology such as aspect, joinpoint, pointcut, advice, cross-cutting concern. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44234446/1082681) might help you as a starting point, but you should read some documentation or tutorial as well. :-) I your case, `logTimeMethod` is the advice and the string inside `@Around()` or `@Pointcut()` is the pointcut. Joinpoints are where your advice injects cross-cutting behaviour.

Comment: @kriegaex, I can appreciate your frustration. I had not read the string (which is someone else’s work) carefully enough. I can assure you I understand operator precedence. Again, this was a colleague’s work that I was attempting to modify, and no, I’m not at all familiar with AOP. But as usual, the input of people such as yourself has helped tremendously.

Comment: You say it is still not working even though Simon's solution looks fine to me. So the next step would be to condense your setup into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem, ideally incl. Maven build, post it on GitHub  and add a link to your question here. The thing with AOP is that you can only analyse and debug if you have both aspect and application code because the former gets woven into the latter. In Spring AOP it is even more complex because the Spring configuration also plays a role, so I would also like to see that.